# why is a click on an element prompting a click on the checkbox next to it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which consists of the questionmark which opens a modal window and a checkbox with its own label to its right. My problem is, every time I click on the questionmark to open the modal window I find that the checkbox is also clicked on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html  >
<html lang="en" style="background:  #fffff0;">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="upload.css">
        <script type=text/javascript src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body ><div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3" for="vertreterCheckbox" id="vertreterLbl">
                            <div class="inline-help form-label" data-help="&lt;b&gt;Sie
  &lt;/div&gt;
" data-heading="Wie kann ich verdeutlichen, dass ich lediglich als Stellvertreter auftrete?" data-help-key="offers.deputy"><i onClick="keyDown(vertreterModal);myFunction('vertreterModal','vertreterOK')"  class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="vertreterHilfe"></i></div>in Vertretung</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input name="offer[deputy]" type="hidden" value="0">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="offer[deputy]" id="vertreterCheckbox">
                                <label for="vertreterCheckbox"  id="vertreterCheckboxLbl">in Vertretung</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    


    <script src="uploadScript.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the following .js code to bring the checkbox back to its previous state:

```
if(event.target.id==="vertreterHilfe"){
        if(document.getElementById("vertreterCheckbox").checked===true){
            document.getElementById("vertreterCheckbox").checked=false
        }else{
                        document.getElementById("vertreterCheckbox").checked=true

        }
    }
```

But I don't really know html/javascript programming and feel like thats not a neat solution. I'd much rather find out, what's causing the problem behaviour and change it rather than a dirty workaround. How can I do it?

Comment: Your first `label` also has `for="vertreterCheckbox"` set - so of course it triggers that checkbox as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `label` element has `for="vertreterCheckbox"` and your checkbox has `id="vertreterCheckbox"`. That links them together, telling the browser that clicking the label should toggle the checkbox.

You also have invalid markup there. You can't have a [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) *inside* a [`label`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element). The content model of `label` is phrasing content; `div`s are allowed in flow and palpable content, not phrasing content. That means the browser can reorganize things as it sees fit to try to make it valid, which may not be the way you want it to be. Move the `div` *out* of the `label`.